# Double partial template specialization for a class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, partial, specialization

I've stumbled upon a little problem with a little code I'm doing while learning c++11/14. Basically I have a Debugging class which I want to handle all the message printing. Most debugging/logging classes have log levels of sorts, but I want to use a flag for **each** message I have.

For that I have a little enum where I define my flags and their values:

```
enum DebugFlag {
    Flag1 = 0,
    Flag2 = 1,
    Flag3 = 2
};
```

Aditionally, I have a Debugging class, which I've managed to specialize for Flag types and it works pretty well.

```
template<DebugFlag T>
class Debug {
public:
    template <typename U>
    static void print(U &&arg) {}
};

template <>
class Debug<static_cast<DebugFlag>(1)> {
public:
    static void print(std::string &&message) {
        std::cerr<<message<<"\n";
    }

    static void print(std::ostream &message) {
        std::cerr<<DebugStream()().str()<<"\n"; 
        DebugStream()().str(""); 
        DebugStream()().clear();  
    }

    static void print(std::string &message) {
        std::cerr<<message<<"\n";
    }
};
```

To call this class, I use a call like:

```
Debug<Flag1>::print("Message\n"); // should not do anything with Flag1 compiled to 0 value
Debug<Flag2>::print("Message\n"); // should work
```

Now I wanted to expand this class to also take `bool` values, so calls like this will work:

```
Debug< Flag2<2 >::print("Message\n"); // should not do anything with Flag1 compiled to 2 value
Debug< Flag2<1 >::print("Message\n"); // should work
```

The problem is I need a second partial specialization for my Debug class, that is `bool`, and I can't figure exactly what the syntax is for this. 
This is the closest I've come to it, but still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or if it's possible without making a secondary class and changing the way I want my call to look like: http://cpp.sh/6yemn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand exactly how you want to be able to use your class, but here's something that works.

```
template <typename T, T v = T()>
class Debug {};

template <>
class Debug<Flag, Flag2> {
public:
    void f() { std::cout<<"This is good\n"; }
};

template <>
class Debug<bool, true> {
public:
    void f() { std::cout<<"This is good too\n"; }
};
```

The problem is that you need to specify the type : whether you want to use a `bool` or a `Flag`, and then the value. You can instantiate the class like so :

```
Debug<bool, true> trueDebug;
Debug<Flag, Flag2> flag2Debug;
```

Other instances won't have the `f` function unless you add a specialization. For example :

```
template <Flag v>
class Debug<Flag, v> {
public:
    void f() { std::cout<<"This is bad\n"; }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2b6845d92bbb2d5)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Maybe I might've confused the example with the `Debug<bool>`, `int` and `Flag` example. In reality all my calls will be either `Debug<true>`, `Debug<false>,` or `Debug<Flag::SomeFlag>`.  

What I gathered from your response is that there's no way for me to have 2 partial implementations of 2 different types (i.e boolean's true and all flags that are equal to 1) using 1 template parameter (as in the code I provided in the question, not the link which works).

Comment: c++17 would allow to get rid of the first parameter, so to have expected syntax. (with `template <auto v> class Debug;`)

Comment: For my curiosity, mind telling me what to search or provide a link for the c++17 draft? I've really searched for this particular problem a good few hours because it seemed solvable somehow.

The sad part is that I could've done this very easily using `#defines`, but I'm trying to avoid them altogether now in c++ for const/constexpr and templates, but it's not always so easy to get it right.

Comment: @PirvuMihai-Cristian: Found that: [Declaring non-type template parameters with auto](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html)